# Console application is displaying incorrect answer for radius of a circle

Tags: c#, console-application

just making a simple console application that displays the area of a circle to the user.  With my current code the result received is "The area of the circle is: geometry"  and NOT a numerical value.   I've been trying all day and getting nowhere... I'm certain I'm doing something really stupid, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
public static void circle() {
    int radius;
    geometry circleArea = new geometry();

    Console.Write("\nEnter The Radius Of Your Circle:  ");
    radius = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("\nThe area of the circle is: {0:f3}", circleArea);
    // wait
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// calculate the area of a circle
public double squareSum(int radius) {
    return (Math.PI * (radius * radius));
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the geometry object circleArea?

Comment: Your string in `Console.Write` has a floating point string formatter, so it is expecting `circleArea` to be a numeric type. You're passing in a variable of type `geometry`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.Write("\nThe area of the circle is: {0:f3}", squareSum(radius));
```